# Android Arabic Cursor Split

Tags: android, android-edittext, arabic

I'm using a custom EditText because client wants to force arabic locale globally in the app.

Here is the code I use in the constructor of the EditText:

```
setTextDirection(TEXT_DIRECTION_LOCALE);
```

It works perfectly, but I have a strange behavior of the cursor as you can see in the image

[image]

Somebody knows if it's normal or how can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: it's normal in some devices , I also see this happen sometimes in Google Apps

Comment: have you got the solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution there: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/39639
Apparently, it's the normal behavior when you have rtl and ltr text mixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behaviour. But if you still want to forcefully acheive this, than this worked for me:

`ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(edtEmail, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);`

along with the gravity field