# Double cursor in EditText for Input Type Number/Phone (RTL Arabic)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype, arabic-support

I have an EditText set to gravity Right, so that the text starts from the right if the language is Arabic.

Note: My application supports RTL, and I am not setting the TextDirection for my EditText as that will have the same problem. Gravity set to Right does the job perfectly. I have an issue only if I set the InputType to Number or Phone.

If the InputType is set to number/phone there are double cursor at the beginning and end of the text and it is a bit confusing.

To demonstrate this, I have two EditText with InputType Text and Number, Gravity set to Right for both. My application supports RTL and My phone is now set to Arabic language

Manifest

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

XML

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="text"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/phone"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            />
```

Here is a screen shot of the behaviour for the second EditText with InputType Number.

Any pointers on how to get rid of the double cursor? or any alternative.

Thanks
R

[image]

Comment: I am getting single cursor on setting number in edittext.

Comment: Thank you for your message. Is your language set to Arabic?

Comment: The behavior is normal when mixing Arabic with English I don't see where the mix is but I dunno.... check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011074/android-arabic-cursor-split

Comment: @MohammadTabbara Yeah I did see that message, if we set the TextDIrection for an EditText, that is a normal behaviour, but if we set the Gravity to Right and TextInput to Text it is normal as in my first EditText example. Only if I have InputType as Number/Phone it has double cursor. So though in case any one found a fix for this.

Comment: @BRDroid have you  got the solution for it, I am also getting same issue , please help me out ,I am stuck with this

Answer (score 2):

Use properties layout_direction as 'ltr' and gravity 'right'.

```html
      <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/phone"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="right" />
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Edit text doesn't know if the next char you will press is a number or a letter so in case of a letter it places the far left one while the far right one for a number(Most likely you know that just making sure).

So it will disappear if you switch to English.

I think this is fundamental in the edit text:

Solutions:

1- You can create your own edit text from scratch(From View).(May take month with all the problems that may arise).

2- Find a way to override the edit text to remove the split.

3- Find a git where someone had solved that problem(which I doubt).

---

This doesn't seem like a problem as a programmer or a user. A designer maybe will be a bit annoyed but ignoring it is the fastest way.

Sorry if this wasn't usefull.

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(findViewById(R.id.myedittext), ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
```

**it worked for me.**

Answer (score 0):

wrap your edittext in linearlayout with horizontal oriation and layoutDirection ltr

Answer (score 0):

try to change `android:inputType="number"` into phone..

for example :

```
   <com.test.utils.custom.CustomTelephone
    android:id="@+id/custom_telephone"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:text="@string/telephone_number_title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_logo" />
```

that worked for me ..

if not work try to add layoutDirection:Rtl in edit Text as attribute ..
Happy coding .. !