# Two cursors are appearing in Xamarin.Forms.Entry when enter arabic letters and numbers in Entry field. How to fix this

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How to prevent one cursor which is come in right side after enter arabic numbers. Is it correct or not. Two cursors are appearing in Xamarin.Forms.Entry when enter arabic letters and numbers in Entry field.
Please any help would be appreciate...

Thanks
praveen

[Please see the screenShot in kitkat device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15eo5.png)

Comment: Does this happen with Android,iOS, or both?
can you share a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Thanks for reply Ali. Please see the screenshot in the above link.

Comment: It's clear now. Since the direction is RTL when you typed in Arabic, it will create another cursor when you type the numbers which is LTR. I am not sure if there is a specific solution in Xamarin because this issue is general in Android and may require a custom solution. This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497850/double-cursor-in-edittext-for-input-type-number-phone-rtl-arabic